# Error in training a merged model in Keras

Tags: keras, image-classification, prediction, training

I attempted to merge a VGG-16 and ResNet-50 model in Keras to benefit from the combined feature representations toward a binary classification task. I was successful in building and saving the merged model. However, while training, I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
#load libraries
import numpy as np
from keras import applications
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense
from keras.layers import Concatenate
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix,accuracy_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from evaluation import plot_confusion_matrix
from keras.models import load_model
from scipy import interp
from itertools import cycle
###############################################################################
#image dimensions and loading
img_width, img_height = 1024,1024
train_data_dir = 'china_whole/train'
validation_data_dir = 'china_whole/test'
epochs = 30 
batch_size = 2 
num_classes= 2
###############################################################################
''' Building a merge of two models'''
base_model1 = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width,img_height,3))
#get the model summary
base_model1.summary()
#addind the top layers
x1 = base_model1.output
x1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x1) #analogous to flatten()
model1 = Model(inputs=base_model1.input, outputs=x1)
model1.summary()
#load the second model ########################################################
base_model2 = applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width,img_height,3))
#get the model summary
base_model2.summary()
#addind the top layers
x2 = base_model2.output
x2 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x2) #analogous to flatten()
model2 = Model(inputs=base_model2.input, outputs=x2)
model2.summary()
###############################################################################
'''merge the models'''
mergedOut = Concatenate()([model1.output,model2.output]) #this is concatenating the two GAP layers
#add a new dense layer and softmax
out=Dense(2048, activation='relu')(mergedOut) 
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(out)
#create the new model with three branches and one dense layer
model = Model(inputs=[model1.input,model2.input], outputs=out)
model.summary()
#fix the optimizer
sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True) 
#the values are computed by a randomized gird search method
#compile the gpu model
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
###############################################################################
#declaring image data generators
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2.0,rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)
nb_train_samples = len(train_generator.filenames)
nb_validation_samples = len(validation_generator.filenames)
#check the class indices
train_generator.class_indices
validation_generator.class_indices
###############################################################################
#start training

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,verbose=1, workers=1)
```

The error when running model.fit_generator was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-62-ab7292930748>", line 6, in <module>
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,verbose=1, workers=1)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2224, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1877, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1476, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 86, in _standardize_input_data
    str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[0.17478053, 0.17478053, 0.17478053],
         [0.17482202, 0.17482202, 0.17482202],
         [0.17394349, 0.17394349, 0.17394349],
         ...,
         [0.15611881, 0.15611881, 0.15611881...
```

How can i resolve this issue in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. while training, I need to pass the training and validation twice like this:

```
model.fit([X_train, X_train], Y_train,..., validation_data=([X_valid, X_valid], Y_valid)).
```